# hg ignore all dlls under a folder

Tags: mercurial, ignore, hgignore

I'm having trouble getting this to work

[image]

I want to exclude all .dll files under the folder VirtualDlls.

I've been trying with regex and with globals but I either am getting all files excluded or none.

Global

```
ScriptCode.ConvertedToC#/VirtualDlls/**.dll
```

gets none of the files

Regex:

```
^ScriptCode.ConvertedToC#/VirtualDlls/.+/.+.dll$
```

Gets all of the files including ones ending in .cs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to keep it simple and understand that matches are not rooted, as explained in the `hgignore` documentation.

If you want to exclude any file ending in `.dll`, no matter where they are, then this works:

```
syntax: glob
*.dll
```

If you want to exclude only below the `VirtualDlls` directory (non-recursive):

```
syntax: glob
VirtualDlls/*.dll
```

If you want to exclude only below the `VirtualDlls` directory, in a recursive way, then you have two options.

The long one: one rule per directory level:

```
syntax: glob
VirtualDlls/*.dll
VirtualDlls/*/*.dll
```

The short one: use `**`:

```
syntax: glob
VirtualDlls/**.dll
```

In your example you use `**` too, but I think it doesn't work because it contains also the first directory, `ScriptCode.ConvertedToC#`.

I tested all the examples and they all work (tested on Mac, but I don't see why they shouldn't work also on Windows).

Comment: Yes... for some reason this does not work: "ScriptCode.ConvertedToC#/VirtualDlls/**.dll" but this does:  "VirtualDlls/**.dll".  Makes perfects sense to me ;-)